# Datameer Multiple Join (Replicating Access Queries in Datameer v6

Tags: ms-access, join

I am trying to re build Microsoft Access queries in Datameer v6. I am fairly new to Datameer so I do not have that much experience.

I am trying to determine the order of which Datameer executes its joins, like for example is it enough to just keep adding joins within the same sheet or do I have to join 2 sheets, then use the joined sheet as the final product for the next join.

Here is my Access join statement

```
Team_Template_ID INNER JOIN (dbo.Cabinet LEFT JOIN 
(((((((((dbo.Procedure RIGHT JOIN dbo.Folder ON dbo.Procedure.FolderID = dbo.Folder.ID) 
LEFT JOIN Example ON dbo.Procedure.Step = Example.CategoryID) 
LEFT JOIN Example AS Example_1 ON dbo.Procedure.CategoryCID = Example_1.CategoryID) 
LEFT JOIN Example AS Example_2 ON dbo.Procedure.VisitCID = Example_2.CategoryID) 
LEFT JOIN Example AS Example_3 ON dbo.Procedure.LocationCID = Example_3.CategoryID) 
LEFT JOIN Example AS Example_4 ON dbo.Procedure.FrequencyCID = Example_4.CategoryID) 
LEFT JOIN Example AS Example_5 ON dbo.Procedure.UserType1CID = Example_5.CategoryID) 
LEFT JOIN Example AS Example_6 ON dbo.Procedure.UserType2CID = Example_6.CategoryID) 
LEFT JOIN Example AS Example_7 ON dbo.Procedure.IndustryCID = Example_7.CategoryID) ON dbo.Cabinet.ID = dbo.Folder.CabinetID) ON Team_ID.Team_ID = dbo.Cabinet.ID
```

Do I do a "Simple" join on datameer then click the "+" button to add additional joins and follow my Microsoft access join sequence?

Cheers

Comment: I'd suggest trying the Datameer community forum - https://datameer.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/community/posts

Answer (score 0):

The first plus sign lets you make join operation on the same table with different columns, and the second one lets you join a table with other tables.

[image: Datameer join interface]